# Считывание изменений содержимого файла

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Некоторая программа постоянно дописывает определённое кол-во строк в N-е число файлов. Мне необходимо в цикле проверять изменился ли файл, и если в него что-то дописали, то считать эту информацию. Все файлы имеют обычное расширение txt. 
Существует ли уже готовое решение во фрейморке qt? так сказать "из коробки".

Comment: именно то, что вы хотите - "из коробки" не существует

Comment: Есть такая штука QFileSystemWatcher, она позволит отследить факт изменения файла. Можно раз в некоторое время проверять контрольную сумму файла, если она изменилась, значит что-то записано. Это два варианта навскидку в зависимости от исходных требований (от требуемой оперативности реагирования программы-читалки на изменение файла)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такой велосипед `tail` из `GNU core utilities`.

```
# dpkg -S  `which tail`
coreutils: /usr/bin/tail
```

Можно запустить `tail -F /var/log/*.log`, `-F` - флаг говорит утилите следить за изменениями.

Таким образом Ваша задача решается.

Сырцы tail на `c`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c

Кошмарные конечно, но всего 2400 строк.

2234 `int main (int argc, char **argv) {`

там заполняются хидеры( заголовки ) потом на строке

2328  `for (i = 0; i < n_files; i++) ok &= tail_file (&F[i], n_units);`

запускается матрёшка из tail-ов на файлы, которые уже в заголовках лежат.

1885 `static bool tail_file (struct File_spec *f, uintmax_t n_units) {`

внутри вызывается просто tail()

1871 `static bool tail (const char *filename, int fd, uintmax_t n_units,       uintmax_t *read_pos)`

там вызывается `tail_lines()`

1809 `static bool tail_lines (const char *pretty_filename, int fd, uintmax_t n_lines, uintmax_t *read_pos)`

И дальше там просто lseek-ами куски вытягиваются... Вообщем, может поможет.

В крайнем случае, можно запустить `tail -F {Ваш,Список,Файлов}` как subprocess, и ловить pipe с него...